# Wikimedia image captions

Tags: wikipedia, wikimedia-commons, wikimedia-dumps

What is the best way to obtain captions and descriptions for most/all images at Wikimedia commons (I do not need the images themselves). I know there is API, but I would prefer to obtain the information in bulk.

For example, when I look at [https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Schloss_Schönbühel_20180919.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Schloss_Sch%C3%B6nb%C3%BChel_20180919.jpg), I see at least a German and English summary. I assume this is in some table in a structured way. I looked at http://dumps.wikimedia.org/commonswiki/latest/commonswiki-latest-image.sql.gz, but this file seems to contain only basic image metadata (size, date, ...)

I am aware of [Get depictions from Wikimedia Commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156241/get-depictions-from-wikimedia-commons), it addresses a related but different problem: `depicts` are a recently introduced [structured data feature](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Depicts) and the answer explains how to obtain the data one-by-one using Wikibase APIs not in bulk in a dump.

-- UPDATE --

It seems that the information is contained in `commonswiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2` (one of the dumps at https://dumps.wikimedia.org/commonswiki/latest/) but has to be extracted from the semi-structured text of each page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get depictions from Wikimedia Commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156241/get-depictions-from-wikimedia-commons)

Comment: It is related, but (1) I need it for all images (I have edited the Q to make it clear), (2) if I understand it correctly `depicts` is a new functionality based on wikibase that is available only for some images, while descriptions are available for all of them.

Comment: The description you see in the file information tab is also new functionality and can be retrieved the same way. If you are looking for the description in the summary box, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CommonsMetadata#Usage . The latter cannot be downloaded in bulk, the former is part of the content dumps as you noted. See [T221917](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T221917) for ongoing work on a separate dump.